# Permute a list of elements given a pattern

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

I have this function `f` and a pattern

```
pattern = f[h[x]]f[h[y]]
```

where `h` is a generic function. Now, I have a set of two distinct functions `list = {h1,h2}`

How can I generate a function `F[pattern_, list_]` which returns the following result?

```
F[pattern,list]
(* f[h1[x]]f[h2[y]]+f[h2[x]]f[h1[y]] *)
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work for any pattern with any number of `h`-functions?

Comment: Yes, You can have for example the patter `pattern=f[g[h[x]]]f[h[y]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we define a replacement rule that replaces each occurrence of an expression with another expression:

```
replaceIteratively[expr_, x_, list_] := Module[{n = 0},
  expr /. x :> (n++; list[[n]])
]
```

such that, e.g.,

```
replaceIteratively[{x, x, k, x}, x, {a, b, c}]
(* {a, b, k, c} *)
```

Then, `F` can be defined as

```
F[pattern_, x_, list_] := 
Total@Table[
  replaceIteratively[pattern, x, newh], 
  {newh, Permutations[list]}
]
```

such that

```
F[f[h[x]] f[h[y]], h, {h1, h2}]
(* f[h1[y]] f[h2[x]] + f[h1[x]] f[h2[y]] *)
```

and

```
F[f[g[h[x]]] f[h[y]], h, {h1, h2}]
(* f[g[h2[x]]] f[h1[y]] + f[g[h1[x]]] f[h2[y]] *)
```

The ordering is not as in your example, but this does not matter since `+` is commutative.

Comment: Thanks you! this solved my problem